# Python-Django Paypal Advanced

Tags: django, django-paypal

Paypal payments advanced integration with Python-Django. I am creating the ecommerce site in django. I need to integrate the paypal payments advanced . But i can't see any tutorial for that integration.

Comment: check this http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [django-paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal) app. It has pretty good docs. And [here](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a docs for django-paypal.

Comment: Thanks Aldarund. django-paypal documention mentioned the paypal-pro and paypal-standard . So how i used to the paypal advanced payment ? If u have suggestion please mentioned. Advanced Thanks to all ..

Comment: django-paypal should work for you. Look at  docs at section Using PayPal Payments Pro (WPP)

Comment: Link to the tutorial are not work anymore.

Comment: https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/